# External List not returning values

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-designer, bcs, external-content-type

**I have an external list which isn't returning any values.**

The list uses an external content type, which gets information from a SOAP service.

After creating the content type using a read item and read list operation, I then created an new external list based on the new external content type.

All the SOAP request returns is some property codes and additional information about the properties.

I have no idea why it's not returning data. I'm after some advice about where I can look to investigate further? If no data is being returned I can only assume that something is perhaps wrong with the SOAP request itself. Does SharePoint have logs somewhere containing errors or information about what might be happening?

Sorry for the lack of information on this question, but with SharePoint problems I rarely know where to start in terms of debugging and google doesn't seem to be much help either.

Big thanks to any advice that can be offered to me.

Comment: Try to make a console/windows forms app first and request SOAP Service to see if it returns data or not! If it does, then problem seems to be from SharePoint... If it doesn't, you will have the exception you are looking for! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take a look into SharePoint ULS logs. Usualy you can find it here:
C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\Logs

Also you can use UlsViewer to view logs. You can download it [here](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/ULSViewer/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=3308)

Comment: This isn't an answer to the question... it's a how do.  Can @MalcomDurling please post what the answer/solution was?